# Can I use custom events for control flow in a Node.js / Express app?

Tags: node.js, express

I have been researching various techniques (mostly async vs. promises) of control flow in NodeJS/Express apps for a few days now and I can't find anyone using custom events (extended by Express) to handle it... which begs the question, why?

I have some concerns around the events being emitted at the app level (scoping conflicts when multiple users are triggering the same event tree?) as well as some concerns around best practices for passing the req and res objects around so much. I'm not quite sure if one of those is a "deal-killer" for this control flow technique, but I'd love some input from the community and some thoughts on why this is a good or bad idea.

Here is some pseudo-code of what I'm thinking:

```
class app.SessionController

    # validate & wash user entry
    @login = (req, res, userData) ->
        # // do stuff //
        app.emit 'session:userEntryValid', req, res, userData


    # see if user-entered passwrod and stored password match
    @validatePassword = (req, res, usr) ->
        # // do stuff //
        app.emit 'session:passwordAccepted', req, res, usr


    # set session variables and send to index
    @loginSuccess = (req, res, usr) ->
        # // do stuff //
        res.redirect '/'


###
SET UP EVENT LISTENERS
###

# Get user from database
app.on 'session:userEntryValid', (req, res, userData) ->
    app.Model.getUser(req, res, userData)

# Validate the password
app.on 'Model:User:emailFound', (req, res, usr) ->
    app.SessionController.validatePassword(req, res, usr)

# Process successful login
app.on 'session:passwordAccepted', (req, res, usr) ->
    app.SessionController.loginSuccess(req, res, usr)
```

Comment: The main 'problem' with events is that they're non linear. A promise gives you a guarantee that it only resolves _once_, it's a one time thing. Events are harder to track, there is no single "one line after the other" place in your code where you can tell exactly what causes what. That said, events are probably one of the most widely used control constructs in JavaScript today.

Comment: Update: I confirmed my original concerns around the events being global to the app. For example, if 2 users were logging in at the same exact time, the app would emit events that could get crossed with each other.

Since I am using coffeescript, I ended up using [nextflow](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-nextflow) which provided the simplicity and results I needed for control flow.